# Black and green patches at the inside of vaccum

Tags: food-safety, meat

Is it safe to eat this ribeye? It has some green and black patches inside of the vacuum. It was in the freezer for 2 months.

[image]

Comment: the green patches look like tiny leaves, at least with the quality of the image you put here. I can't tell what the black is, not enough detail in the image.

Comment: I'm quite puzzled by the question. I see two green leaves, like Esther, and three small black seeds which remind me of black caraway. It's very obvious that they aren't spots within the meat. I also see that the meat surface isn't bright red, but it has the slightly greyish look of oxygenated meat, and no noticeable spots. What is it that you're asking about, is it the spices, or are you seeing something on the meat that isn't clear in the photo?

Comment: The black and green do not look like results of the time in the freezer. If that meat is packed vacuum, those leaves were already in it. Did the vacuum break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good, I ate it and it was all fine.